# How can I programmatically flip the value of an element attribute using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, attributes, toggle

I'm just starting to get into JQuery so I apologize in advance if this is a simple question.

I'm working with the [A List Apart article on Print Previews](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/printtopreview/) to try to get live Print Previews in the webapp that I'm working on.  I've gotten it to work satisfactorily but I'm now trying to refactor my code to what I think it should look like internally.  I currently have 2 sets of methods, one for displaying the block of microcopy and the other for removing it.  I'd much rather just have a single set that toggles the appropriate values of the elements in question.

For the CSS that means disabling the non-print-preview sheets and enabling the print-preview one, and vice-versa.  For my microcopy, that means setting `display` to `block` rather than `none`, again vice-versa.

At least for the the stylesheet links, I want to simply loop through the collection of related `link` elements and set `disabled` to `!disabled` but I can't figure out how to do that.  I'm using jQuery but I'm not opposed to dropping below that level of abstraction.

I assume once I know how to do that for the `link` elements I should be able to extend the solution to also toggle the `display` attribute of the microcopy div.

Here's my current functions for the curious:

```
function printPreview() {
    $("link[rel*='style'][media!='print'").attr("disabled", true);
    $("link[rel*='style'][title='print preview']").attr("disabled", false);
    addPrintPreviewMicrocopy();
}

function addPrintPreviewMicrocopy() {
    $("div[id='print-preview-microcopy']").css({'display':'block'});
}

function normalView() {
    $("link[rel*='style'][media!='print'").attr("disabled", false);
    $("link[rel*='style'][title='print preview']").attr("disabled", true);
    removePrintPreviewMicrocopy();
}

function removePrintPreviewMicrocopy() {
    $("div[id='print-preview-microcopy']").css({'display':'none'});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks everyone.  Here's my final solution:

```
function toggleView() {
    $("link[rel*='style'][media!='print']").each( function() {
        this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    });
}
```

It turns out that I didn't even need to toggle the div as the stylsheets alone did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `<link>` elements you can toggle their `disabled` attribute with:

```
$('link[rel*=style]').each(function(){
  this.disabled = !this.disabled
})
```

This works because that attribute specifically is a read/write `boolean` property for `<link>` elements.

As for the divs you can use [`toggle()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle) as others suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You can toggle show/hide with the `toggle` function:

```
function removePrintPreviewMicrocopy() {
    $("div[id='print-preview-microcopy']").toggle();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for the microcopy div.  My code ended up being `$("#print-preview-microcopy").toggle()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `disabled` HTML attribute is not technically boolean.  It's an enumerable with either a value of "" or "disabled".

The `disabled` DOM property, however, *is* a boolean.

```
$('selector').attr( "disabled", "" );
$('selector').each( function() { this.disabled = false; } );
```

Also, your ID selectors are too complicated

```
$("div[id='print-preview-microcopy']")
```

should be

```
$("#print-preview-microcopy")
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Forgive me if I'm missing something but I can't tell how your code allows me to toggle the value of disabled on all the selected elements.  I don't just want to turn it off, I want to go from on to off to on, etc.  Thanks for further explanation.

Comment: Roatin Marth's answer shows how.  I was just merely making the distinction between HTML attributes and DOM properties

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the show() and hide() methods.

```
$("#selector").show();
$("#selector").hide();
```

Or you could use a nice fade if you prefer.

```
$("#selector").fadeIn("slow");
$("#selector").fadeOut("slow");
```

It should be noted that "#selector" should be relpaced with the div id or the html tag in question.